# Pandas: label with a given set of yaxis values category plot

Tags: python, pandas

The csv has the following values

```
Name       Grade
Jack       B
Jill       C
```

The labels for the y-axis are B and C from the CSV. But i want the y axis to contain all the grades- A,B,C,D,F .This plots only the given values in the y-axis(B,C),

`ax = sns.catplot(x = "Name", y = "Grade")`

Is there any possible way to give all the grades in the y-axis to plot.

Comment: Do you want to draw a plot with categorical values?

Comment: Not really. Just a way to get more values in the y-axis which are not specified in the csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `sns.catplot()` without the `kind` argument, it invokes the default `sns.stripplot`, which only works if `y` is numerical. So if you really want this kind of plot, you should code the grades as numbers. You can still show the grade letters in the plot, by assigning them as labels:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# code grades as numbers (A: 1 etc.)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Jack', 'Jill'], 
                   'Grade': [2, 3]})

# catplot (i.e. the default stripplot) works, as y is numerical
sns.catplot(x='Name', y='Grade', data=df)

# provide y tick positions and labels (translate numbers back to grade letters)
plt.yticks(range(1, 7), [chr(ord('A') + i) for i in range(6)])
```

[image: grades plot]

*Edit:* If you want to have A on top, just add this line at the end:

```py
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: You may want to reverse order to show A grade on top,

Comment: Sure, that's easy to do. I added the code to my answer.

Comment: I Got it. But to plot some strings on the axis "Good","Fair","Excellent", "Bad" which are not in the csv, will this work out?

Comment: @Sam, yes, you can replace `[chr(ord('A') + i) for i in range(6)]` in my code with any list of strings you like as labels.

Comment: By replacing the labels of the yaxis changes. But how to map it to the values in the csv. Because while plotting many disappear and the plot isnt in its place. When i give plt.yticks(range(1, 7), ['Good','Bad','A','B','C','D',F']) the graph is not as i want. i get an error when i give plt.yticks(range(1, 7),Grade= ['Good','Bad','A','B','C','D',F']). Is there a way to map the column values of the csv to the labels?

Comment: @Sam you get that error because the number of labels has to be the same as the number of ticks, and `plt.yticks()` does not take `Grade` as a keyword (and you were missing a quote before the F). But you can pass any predefined list of labels. E.g. `Grades = ['Good', 'Bad', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']` and then `plt.yticks(range(1, len(Grades) + 1), Grades)` should work. Just make sure that list corresponds to your numbers coding the grades.